# Python-Big Query-Updating the rows in the existing table if exist otherwise create one

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery, sql-update

I am calling API to run after updated_at timestamp by calling the ID.
The values are going into big query table

```
pandas.to_gbq("tablename",projectname,chunksize=None,if_exists='append')
```

I want do modify the existing row in the big query table if API returns the same id if it doesnt exists then make it a new row.

Comment: Could you post sample data and desired outputs? So I can investigate further and write a code.

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes 
Now I am getting the updated last row in Python Big query connector and passing that id to API from which I am calling the data.Now what is happening is when I pass the ID and if it exists in Big query table let say this xxx.xxxx then it is just adding upto one more table making it as a duplicate not a update.

                 cols=['abcd,'efgh','ijkl', 
                dfM=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=cols)
                lst = list(dfM)
                dfM[lst] = dfM[lst].astype(str)
             dfM.to_gbq('xxx.xxxx','xxxxProjectname',chunksize=None,if_exists='append')